# firebase StorageException gets printed, even though I handle it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to check if a file exists in Firebase storage and if so update its metadata. 
OnFailureListener works as intended like this:

```
storageRef.child("users/me/file.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // File not found
    }
});
```

However, I get this error trace on logcat:

```
2020-05-21 01:45:04.484 10910-11160/pl.edu.mimuw.exshare E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-05-21 01:45:04.489 10910-11160/pl.edu.mimuw.exshare E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetMetadataTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:61)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Is there any way I can stop this error message from being printed?

Answer (score 0):

If the storage SDK prints something to the log, there's nothing you can do to change that behavior, other than building the SDK yourself from [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-storage), and removing the logging that you don't want.

Or, you can just ignore the log.  Or you can file an issue on GitHub and ask the developers to remove it.